# MLE for $\Sigma$ based on sequences of observations

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution, maximum-likelihood

Given $\bf{x}$$_1$,...,$\bf{x}$$_n$ be a sequence of random vectors that are independent and identically distributed from $N_p(\mu_0,\Sigma)$ where $\mu_0$ is known.

(i) Show that the MLE for $\Sigma$ is;

$$
\widehat{\Sigma}=\frac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{i=1}^n(\mathbf{x}_i-\mu_0)(\mathbf{x}_i-\mu_0)'
$$

(ii) Now let $\bf{y}$$_1$,...,$\bf{y}$$_m$ be another sequence of random vectors that are independent and identically distributed from $N_p(\mu_1,\Sigma)$ where $\mu_1$ is known.  Calculate the MLE for $\Sigma$ based on the sequences of observations {$\bf{x}$$_1$,...,$\bf{x}$$_n$} and {$\bf{y}$$_1$,...,$\bf{y}$$_m$}.  What happens to $\Sigma$ if both $\mu_i$ for $i=0,1$ are assumed to be unknown?

I do not have any questions on part (i), I have already shown that the MLE for $\Sigma$ is indeed $\widehat{\Sigma}$.  My concerns are towards part (ii).   I don't quite understand in what ways $\widehat{\Sigma}$ will change under this scenario and how to represent it notation-wise.  Also, when $\mu_i$ for $i=0,1$ are assumed to be unknown; do we simply replace $\mu_0$ and $\mu_1$ in the new MLE for $\Sigma$ by $\hat{\mathbf{\mu}}_0$ and $\hat{\mathbf{\mu}}_1$?

Any form of help is much appreciated.

Comment: I think you need to find the joint probability $$p(\mathbf{x}_1,\ldots,\mathbf{x}_n,\mathbf{y}_1,\ldots,\mathbf{y}_m)$$ and extract the covariance matrix from that.

Comment: Thus, would claiming $(\mathbf{x}_1,...,\mathbf{x}_n,\mathbf{y}_1,...,\mathbf{y}_n) \sim N_p(n\mu_0+m\mu_1,(n+m)\Sigma)$ and then considering the MLE for $(n+m)\Sigma$ be the correct approach?

Comment: How did you find the covariance in part (i)? I would assume that you found the joint PDF $p(\mathbf{x}_1,\ldots,\mathbf{x}_n)$, which is a multivariate Gaussian distribution, and from there you found the covariance matrix. Here I think it's the same thing, but you need to find the joint PDF $p(\mathbf{x}_1,\ldots,\mathbf{x}_n,\mathbf{y}_1,\ldots,\mathbf{y}_m)$ instead. Since these are independent, this can be written as $$\prod_ip(\mathbf{x}_i)\prod_jp(\mathbf{y}_j)$$

Comment: In part (i) I derived $\widehat{\Sigma}$ by using the maximum likelihood method of finding the log-likelihood, taking the partial derivative with respect to $\Sigma^{-1}$ and setting the equation equal to 0.  I didn't necessarily find $\Sigma$ as you're suggesting.  Maybe I'm just not following what you're saying?

Comment: I'm describing the same thing, I think. You need first to find the joint PDF, find the log-likelihood of that function, and then do the derivation. The joint PDF in the first case is $$\prod_ip(\mathbf{x}_i)$$ while in the second case it will be $$\prod_ip(\mathbf{x}_i)\prod_jp(\mathbf{y}_j)$$ where $$p(\mathbf{x}_i)=\text{det}\left(2\pi\Sigma\right)^{-1/2}\exp\left(-\frac{1}{2}(\mathbf{x}_i-\mu_0)^T\Sigma^{-1}(\mathbf{x}_i-\mu_0)\right)$$ and $$p(\mathbf{y}_j)=\text{det}\left(2\pi\Sigma\right)^{-1/2}\exp\left(-\frac{1}{2}(\mathbf{y}_j-\mu_1)^T\Sigma^{-1}(\mathbf{y}_j-\mu_1)\right)$$

Comment: Right, right, I'm following now.  Thank you, I'll give that a shot